# how to adapt sql server 2008 trigger into mysql trigger as follows

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008

I tried to convert an SQL Server 2008 trigger as follows

```
Create Trigger [dbo].[TRIGGER_NAME] ON [dbo].[table_sale]
For Insert, Update, Delete
As
Select * From INSERTED Update table_stock Set Stock = Stock - Total
From INSERTED where table_stock.barcode = INSERTED.barcode
```

into MySql trigger. I Can't figure out what's INSERTED reffers to, so I just tried to convert as follows:

```
CREATE
TRIGGER `TRIGGER_NAME` AFTER INSERT
ON `table_sale`
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
SELECT * FROM INSERTED UPDATE `table_stock` Set `stock` = `stock` - `total`
FROM INSERTED WHERE `table_stock`.`barcode` = INSERTED.`barcode`
```

then comes the error message after I tried it:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT, UPDATE,
DELETE AS SELECT * FROM INSERTED UPDATE table_stock Set stock = sto' at line 4
```

I'm sure the mySql trigger that I made has so many mistake. I would love to hear input from you all. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to define separate triggers for each action.  The syntax **must** be ``... ON `table_sale` FOR EACH ROW ...``

Comment: I tried ... ON `table_sale` FOR EACH ROW INSERT UPDATE DELETE ... and ended up with this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE DELETE AS SELECT * FROM INSERTED UPDATE table_stock Set stock = stock' at line 6

Comment: As I said, you need to define *seperate* triggers for each action.

Comment: I got it, thanks eggyal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to create a different trigger for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE.

I imagine you would want something like this:

### INSERT:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `TRIGGER_NAME` AFTER INSERT
ON `table_sale` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN    
    UPDATE `table_stock` 
        Set `stock` = `stock` - NEW.`total`     
    WHERE `barcode` = NEW.`barcode`;
END
```

### UPDATE:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `TRIGGER_NAME` AFTER UPDATE
ON `table_sale` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN    
    UPDATE `table_stock` 
        Set `stock` = `stock` - `total`     
    WHERE `barcode` = NEW.`barcode`;
END
```

### DELETE:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `TRIGGER_NAME` AFTER DELETE
ON `table_sale` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    UPDATE `table_stock` 
        Set `stock` = `stock` - `total`     
    WHERE `barcode` = OLD.`barcode`;
END
```

I took the liberty of putting OLD in the DELETE trigger, because there are no NEW records there.

This is more or less what you would do to migrate it exactly, but looking at it in a functional standpoint, it looks like you would have to work on what it does a bit.

1. `total` should probably come from NEW, or OLD, i.e., new would come from table_sale.
2. If on INSERT you subtract from stock, on DELETE you should ADD
3. On UPDATE you should probably subtract the NEW but add the OLD, to end up with the difference.

If this were true, your SET line would be:

**INSERT:**

```
Set `stock` = `stock` - NEW.`total`
```

**UPDATE:**

```
Set `stock` = `stock` - NEW.`total` + OLD.`total`
```

**DELETE**

```
Set `stock` = `stock` + OLD.`total`
```

These are my two cents, but i may be wrong. :)

Comment: Yes, more or less I found it usefull. :) Thanks man. It really helps.